# Exercise in C to calculate sum from x to y

Tags: c, imperative-programming

My teacher wants the sum of all numbers from x to y... like x+(x+1)+(x+2)...until y. But I think I'm doing something wrong here!

Can someone advice me what is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_naturals(int n)
{
  return (n-1) * n / 2;
}

int sum_from_to(int m)
{
  return (m-1) * m / 2;
}

void test_sum_naturals(void)
{
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);
  int z = sum_naturals(x);
  printf("%d\n", z);
}

void test_sum_from_to(void)
{
   int x;
   int y;
   scanf("%d", &x);
   scanf("%d", &y);
   int z = sum_naturals(x);
   int b = sum_from_to(y);
   printf("%d\n", z);
}

 int main(void)
{
 //test_sum_naturals();
  test_sum_from_to();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: sum from x to y is sum from 1 to y minus sum from 1 to x, is this what you're doing ?

Comment: yes but i only get the sum of the x! like if i put on console the x and the y this only will sum the x like if i put 5 this will do 0+1+2+3+4... i want x=5 and Y=10 6+7+8+9+10

Comment: they dont let me use for loops

Comment: You are printing only result of `x`  here `printf("%d\n", z);` in `test_sum_from_to` function. You need `printf("x: %d y: %d \n", z,b);`.

Comment: oohhh god is that :D i need to print z-b!!!! nice man!!! how can i mark this answer with +1?

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues It's ok in comment. Also you haven't sufficient reputation to `+1` my answer if make this comment as answer. Anyway it's fine to see your problem solved.

Comment: I guess your teacher want you to use `for` loop to calculate x to y. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should in fact be:

```
int sum_naturals(int n)
{
    return (n+1) * n / 2;
}

int sum_from_to(int m)
{
    return (m+1) * m / 2;
}
```

Notice `+` instead of your `-`.

To find the sum just add in the function `test_sum_from_to` this line:

```
printf("The sum is %d", b-z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum_naturals(int n)
{
  return (n+1) * n / 2;
}

int sum_from_x_to_y(int x, int y){
    return sum_naturals(y) - sum_naturals(x);
}

main()
{
     printf ("Sum: %d \n",sum_from_x_to_y(5, 10));
     printf ("Sum: %d \n",sum_from_x_to_y(0, 10));
     printf ("Sum: %d \n",sum_from_x_to_y(0, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Note : sum from 0 to N is (n+1)*n/2 and **not** (n-1)*n/2